# How often does the federal government sue states?

Tags: united-states, law, judiciary

The Justice Department recently filed [a lawsuit against the State of Georgia](https://s3.documentcloud.org/documents/20972818/ga-lawsuit.pdf) over voting restrictions passed by the Georgia legislature.

How often does the federal government file lawsuits against states?

(**Note:** This is different from [lawsuits filed *by states*](https://ballotpedia.org/Multistate_lawsuits_against_the_federal_government,_2017-2020) *against* the federal government.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not often. Based on an article issued by the [Cornell Law School](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution-conan/article-3/section-2/clause-1/cases-to-which-the-united-states-is-a-party):

> **The first such suit** occurred in United States v. North Carolina, which was an action by the United States to recover upon bonds issued
> by North Carolina. Although no question of jurisdiction was raised, in
> deciding the case on its merits in favor of the state, the Court
> tacitly assumed that it had jurisdiction of such cases. The issue of
> jurisdiction was directly raised by Texas a few years later in a bill
> in equity brought by the United States to determine the boundary
> between Texas and the Territory of Oklahoma, and the Court sustained
> its jurisdiction over strong arguments by Texas to the effect that it
> could not be sued by the United States without its consent and that
> the Supreme Court’s original jurisdiction did not extend to cases to
> which the United States is a party. Stressing the inclusion within the
> judicial power of cases to which the United States and a state are
> parties, the elder Justice Harlan pointed out that the Constitution
> made no exception of suits brought by the United States. In effect,
> therefore, consent to be sued by the United States “was given by Texas
> when admitted to the Union upon an equal footing in all respects with
> the other States.”
>
> Suits brought by the United States have, however, **been infrequent**.
> All of them have arisen since 1889, and they have become somewhat more
> common since 1926. That year the Supreme Court decided a dispute
> between the United States and Minnesota over land patents issued to
> the state by the United States in breach of its trust obligations to
> the Indian. In United States v. West Virginia, the Court refused to
> take jurisdiction of a suit in equity brought by the United States to
> determine the navigability of the New and Kanawha Rivers on the ground
> that the jurisdiction in such suits is limited to cases and
> controversies and does not extend to the adjudication of mere
> differences of opinion between the officials of the two governments. A
> few years earlier, however, it had taken jurisdiction of a suit by the
> United States against Utah to quiet title to land forming the beds of
> certain sections of the Colorado River and its tributaries with the
> states. Similarly, it took jurisdiction of a suit brought by the
> United States against California to determine the ownership of and
> paramount rights over the submerged land and the oil and gas
> thereunder off the coast of California between the low-water mark and
> the three-mile limit. Like suits were decided against Louisiana and
> Texas in 1950.